# Как написать ввод и вывод в одну строку кода?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Возможно ли написать этот код в одну строку?

код:

```
a=input()

print((a[0].upper())+a[1:])
```

Comment: `print((lambda a: a[0].upper() + a[1:])(input()))`

Comment: @andreymal Красиво! Я уж думал нельзя никак в одной строке `input` получить и обработать не итерируясь. Почему не отдельным ответом? )

Comment: Спасибо за крутое и простое решение.

Answer (score 3):

у строк есть метод `title`

```
print(input().title())
```

Comment: В задаче нужно чтобы все дальнейшие буквы в строке не изменились.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с помощью `lambda` от участника [@andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal)

```
print((lambda a: a[0].upper() + a[1:])(input()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Если `title` не подходит, то можно так, например, но что-то сложновато получилось:

```
print(''.join(a if i else a.upper() for i,a in enumerate(input())))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я знал что простого ответа не может быть)

Comment: @1macan1 Посмотрите комментарий от andreymal к вашему вопросу, там ещё проще вариант )

Comment: Согласен с Вами, там человек ещё проще сделал. Написать решение через одноразовую функцию lambda это очень крутая и простая идея.

Answer (score 2):

```
[(a[0].upper())+a[1:] for a in [input()]][0]
```